# How to modify the default context menu of MainWindow in WPF desktop app

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, desktop

How do I modify the default context menu of MainWindow in WPF desktop app?

Here's the default one:

[image]

Adding the menu items is based on certain conditions, so I need to be able to do this in code rather than XAML.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ( CanShowDevMenu )
        {
            ContextMenu menu = this.ContextMenu;

            if ( menu == null )
            {
                try
                {
                    menu = (ContextMenu)Application.Current.MainWindow.FindResource("WindowContextMenu");
                }
                catch
                {
                    menu = null;
                }
            }

            if ( menu != null )
            {
                MenuItem menuItem1 = new MenuItem() { Header = "Item 1" };
                MenuItem menuItem2 = new MenuItem() { Header = "Item 2" };
                MenuItem menuItem3 = new MenuItem() { Header = "Item 3" };

                menu.Items.Add(menuItem1);
                menu.Items.Add(menuItem2);
                menu.Items.Add(menuItem3);
            }
        }
    }
```

Neither attempt to get the context menu works -- the first returns null and the second throws an exception saying the resource can't be found.

Comment: This is not called a "default context menu" or a "window context menu" and it has nothing to do with `this.ContextMenu;`.  It is called ***The System Menu*** and it is for all practical purposes beyond your reach if you do WPF, unless you are willing to get dirty with PInvoke.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the default context menu on the title bar but you can replace it with your own custom one as examplified [here](https://brianlagunas.com/showing-a-custom-contextmenu-on-a-wpf-window-title-bar/):

```
private const uint WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN = 0xa4;
private const uint HTCAPTION = 0x02;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
}

private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IntPtr windowhandle = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
    HwndSource hwndSource = HwndSource.FromHwnd(windowhandle);
    hwndSource.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(WndProc));
}

private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
    return IntPtr.Zero;
}


private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
    //Message for the right click
    if ((msg == WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN) && (wParam.ToInt32() == HTCAPTION))
    {
        //Show a custom context menu
        ShowContextMenu();

        //prevent default context menu from appearing
        handled = true;
    }

    return IntPtr.Zero;
}

private void ShowContextMenu()
{
    var contextMenu = Resources["contextMenu"] as ContextMenu;
    contextMenu.IsOpen = true;
}
```